# Include Git Library with Project on Android Studio using aar?

Tags: android, git, module, android-studio, android-library

I'm a total beginner with Android Studio and haven't been able to figure out how to get this library to work with my app. Can someone walk me through how to install and use in my project. I tried adding the project as a module but that didn't work for me like other libraries/modules.

Here is the project I'm trying to add:

https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText

Thank you.

EDIT:

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile project(':AndroidBootstrap')
compile project(':android-support-v4-preferencefragment-master')
compile project(':google-play-services_lib_lollipop')
compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:1.7.1'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }



    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried and I just add a line `compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:1.7.1'`
to in the app folder `build.gradle`, such that

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:1.7.1'
}
```

`Sync the gradle`. Then, just use `com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText` instead of `EditText` in your layout xml, such that:

```
<com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:hint="Basic"/>
```

`MaterialEditText` has directly inherited `EditText`, so you don't have to change your java code.

**EDIT**

`build.gradle` in app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:1.7.1'
}
```

`build.gradle` in root

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

settings.gradle

```
include ':app'
```

Comment: when I add compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:1.7.1' it says it couldnt find it, what do I need to do to remedy that? @bjiang

Comment: I have no pro with that. What version of your Android studio? and Did you try create a new project and add it?

Comment: im trying to add it to an existing project, did you download the aar file and import it to android studio (running latest) or did you download whole project and import as module? @bjiang

Comment: You don't need the aar file, it just for eclipse. For Android studio , just add the compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:1.7.1' to your app gradle, that it. You can start a new project and try.

Comment: I dont need to include anything in settings.gradle? because it definitely can't find it for some reason.

Comment: Nothing in my settings.gradle, I will post all my gradle files. See edit

Comment: really appreciate the edit, been trying to look everywhere for the build.gradle in my main but can't find it. the build.gradle in app looks similar but has some differences do to probably it being an import. I'll edit my post to include it.

Comment: Not in your main , it's in your Root

Comment: Being a complete beginner here, I must ask, Where can I find this folder? @bjiang

Comment: Search build.gradle in your whole project, you should find two

Comment: Wow after all that, I finally figured it out, you need to put repositories {
    mavenCentral()
} outside the buildscript, then it would work, thank you for all your help!